# Why does tm_sec range from 0-60 instead of 0-59 in time.h?

Tags: c++, c, time

My `time.h` has the following definition of `tm`:

```
struct tm {
    int tm_sec;     /* seconds after the minute [0-60] */
    int tm_min;     /* minutes after the hour [0-59] */
    int tm_hour;    /* hours since midnight [0-23] */
    ...
}
```

I just noticed that they document `tm_sec` as ranging between **0-60** inclusive. I've always assumed it ranged from 0-59 just like `tm_min`. I've certainly never seen a clock read 10:37:60...

Do you think this is just a documentation bug left over from this 90's era Berkley-originated file?

**Or is there something more subtle going on that I'm unaware of?**

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[Leap seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) are the reason for this:

> A leap second is a plus or minus one-second adjustment to the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) time scale that keeps it close to mean solar time.
>
> When a positive leap second is added at 23:59:60 UTC, it delays the start of the following UTC day (at 00:00:00 UTC) by one second, effectively slowing the UTC clock.

Comment: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/time.h.html and lots of other places tell about this.

Comment: a quote from the C standard would be nice

Comment: @Neil: The C99 standard says this in a footnote: "The range [0,60] for tm_sec allows for a positive leap second."

Comment: And interestingly, the C90 standard says: "The range [0,61] for tm_sec allows for as many as two leap seconds." - What happened in that decade? Is there no longer a need for a second leap second?

Comment: @michael "The formal definition of UTC does not permit double leap seconds, so all mention of double leap seconds has been removed, and the range shortened from the former [0,61] seconds seen in previous versions of POSIX."

Comment: hehe, nice observation. i feel c++1x will specify range as [0,6x] to allow for as many as 10 leap seconds oO

Comment: Or 0x10 leap seconds, if "x" turns out to be a placeholder for a hex digit ;-)

Comment: Someone involved with the C90 standard heard that "there can be up to two leap seconds in a year" and misinterpreted it to mean that they could both occur at once.

Comment: Not misinterpreted, took precautions based on little data.  :-) Just kidding... @dan04

Answer (score 9):

The man page for `ctime` explains that this is about leap seconds:

> `tm_sec`:  The number of seconds after the minute, normally in the  range  0  to
>              59, but can be up to 60 to allow for leap seconds.