# something weird about members of Time.h structure

Tags: c, time.h

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does tm_sec range from 0-60 instead of 0-59 in time.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765778/why-does-tm-sec-range-from-0-60-instead-of-0-59-in-time-h)

So when I looked up `<time.h>` for some info, I ran across this. I'm assuming the numbers in the square brackets are the ranges possible for each respective member of the structure. So why is there 0~61 possible range for seconds? Were there 62 seconds in each minute and I'm the only one who didn't know about it???

```
int    tm_sec   seconds [0,61] // <-- this part is weird
int    tm_min   minutes [0,59]
int    tm_hour  hour [0,23]
int    tm_mday  day of month [1,31]
int    tm_mon   month of year [0,11]
int    tm_year  years since 1900
int    tm_wday  day of week [0,6] (Sunday = 0)
int    tm_yday  day of year [0,365]
int    tm_isdst daylight savings flag
```

Comment: exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765778/why-does-tm-sec-range-from-0-60-instead-of-0-59-in-time-h

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Leap seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second).