# What is the purpose of 61 in tm_sec field from the tm structure

Tags: c++, c

According to the [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/), `tm_sec` field from the `tm` structure accept values from 0 to 61 in C90 and values from 0 to 60 in C99 and later.

I know that 60 can be used to express leap second but what about the other one (I mean 61)? And why did they choose to remove it?

Yeah, I tagged it both C and C++ because it is related to both languages in this case.

Comment: It's asked and answered in the comments on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/765780).

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Are you serious?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/tm#cite_note-leapsecond-1 as possible explanation

Comment: @FrozenHeart Are you actually?

Comment: @Creris So it was a defect? Really?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Did you even read the question?

Comment: I dont know, its just what I found on cppref, but it could very well be

Comment: @FrozenHeart Of course I did. Did you seriously research about the topic?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Does it affect the answer somehow? It's for academic purposes only but does it matter?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This question is so obviously not a duplicate of what you suggested that it's hard for me to believe that you read and understood the question. Giving you the benefit of the doubt: maybe you accidentally pasted the wrong link, and meant to suggest another dupe target? Can you check if you still stand by that comment?

Comment: @hvd OK I posted that for exemplary low research about the topic. There never was a flag (or dupe hammer) with it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: what do you mean by one-based second count?

Comment: @chqrlie: 1 thru 60 instead of 0 thru 59.  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765778/why-does-tm-sec-range-from-0-60-instead-of-0-59-in-time-h/765780#comment3625260_765780) is actually more plausible.

Comment: [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/) is wrong, or at least out of date. C90 incorrectly specified the range as [0, 61], because (IIRC) someone mistakenly thought it was possible to have two consecutive leap seconds. C99 corrected it to [0, 60].

Comment: A correction to my previous comment: [that web page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/) has separate tabs for C90 and C99. The C99 tab shows the correct range [0,60] (but without a comment to explain it). (The emphasis on on C++, but the C++ includes most of the C standard library by reference.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A range of `0` to `61` allows for up to 2 consecutive leap seconds on December 31st of a given year, probably mistakenly because in years that require 2 leap seconds, these are not added on the same day.

Newer versions of the C Standard correctly assume that at most one leap second will be inserted at a time on any given day.

As explained in detail in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second leap seconds are inserted in December and/or June in order to avoid a drift longer than 0.9 second, hence the maximum value for `tm_sec` should be `60` instead of `61`.

Comment: Which, y'know, makes sense, since the formal definition of UTC does not permit double leap seconds.  See the comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/765780/102937).

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I agree, and the reference is quite pertinent, although it is not a duplicate.